# Remove unnecessary whitespace from Jinja rendered template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using `curl` to watch the output of my web app.

When Flask and Jinja render templates, there's a lot of unnecessary white space in the output.
It seems to be added by rendering various components from Flask-WTF and Flask-Bootstrap.

I could strip this using `sed`, but is there a way to control this from Jinja?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Jinja has multiple ways to [control whitespace](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control).  It *does not* have a way to prettify output, you have to manually make sure everything looks "nice".

The broadest solution is to set `trim_blocks` and `lstrip_blocks` on the env.

```
app.jinja_env.trim_blocks = True
app.jinja_env.lstrip_blocks = True
```

If you want to keep a newline at the end of the file, set `strip_trailing_newlines = False`.

You can use control characters to modify how the whitespace around a tag works.  `-` always removes whitespace, `+` always preserves it, overriding the env settings for that tag. The `-` character can go at the beginning or end (or both) of a tag to control the whitespace in that direction, the `+` character only makes sense at the beginning of a tag.

- `{%- if ... %}` strips before
- `{%- if ... -%}` strips before and after
- `{%+ if ... %}` preserves before
- `{%+ if ... -%}` preserves before and strips after
- remember that `{% endif %}` is treated separately

The control characters only apply to templates *you* write.  If you include a template or use a macro from a 3rd party, however they wrote the template will apply to that part.

Answer (score 25):

To collapse whitespace before and after a block:

```
{%- if form.message -%} //trims before
   {{ form.message }}
{%- endif -%} // trims after
```