# Remove blank lines from Django template output of render_to_string

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am trying to add contents to models.py dynamically using templates. For this i have the following line in views.py

```
model_content = render_to_string('myapp/models.txt',{'table':table_name, 'fields':fields})
```

**models.txt in templates**

```
class {{ table }}(models.Model):
{% for field in fields %}
   {{ field.field_name }} = models.{{ field.field_type.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But when i wrote model_content string to a file say models.py i am getting the below

```
class Mytable(models.Model):

    order = models.CharField

    cust_name = models.CharField
```

I am getting an extra line after every line. How to avoid this. I will provide additional information if required.

Comment: I wrote something similar and created a template tag to strip the empty lines. https://github.com/allcaps/django-scaffold/blob/master/scaffold/templatetags/scaffold_tags.py You can also put your forloop on one line. But that makes it harder to read. Something like `{% for field in fields %}    {{ field.field_name }} = ...`

Comment: You could use Jinja2, which [has ways to control whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775207/remove-unnecessary-whitespace-from-jinja-rendered-template).