# How to override Jinja2 extension settings in Cement Framework?

Tags: python, jinja2, cement

I'm a new user of **Cement Framework** and Python. I try to override the default configuration of jinja2 template handler to set trim_blocks to True. I see the default value of Environment settings in the extension, but I really wonder where is the **correct place to override it** in **Cement** ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove unnecessary whitespace from Jinja rendered template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775207/remove-unnecessary-whitespace-from-jinja-rendered-template)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would to know how override settings in Cement Framework, not directly in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests, I found a way to **override Jinja2 extension**. I hope it's a good way to do it.

To avoid doing it directly in the command class, **I used Cement hook** "*post_argument_parsing*". I've defined this hook in the main class in the file "main.py" like this :

```
def jinja2_settings_override(self):
   # Jinja2 Environment context
   env = self.output.templater.env
   env.trim_blocks = True

class MyCommandClass(App):
    """Primary application."""

    class Meta:
        label = 'my_command'

        # ... #

        # register the hook to override jinja2 extension settings.
        hooks = [
            ('post_argument_parsing', jinja2_settings_override),
        ]
```