# 12 spaces added in front and at the end when passing jinja2 variable to HTML and I cannot remove it

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have problem with this 12 whitespaces in front and end of everything I send with Jinja2 to HTML.

I tried almost every advice which I found on web and nothing changes.

routes.py

```py
@app.route("/test", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test():
    form = TestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        output = test_procesing(test_input=form.test_input.data)
        return render_template("test.html", form=form, output=output)
    return render_template("test.html", form=form)
```

test.py

```py
def test_procesing(test_input):
    output = test_input
    return output
```

Template:

```html
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <pre>
            {{ output }}
            </pre>
        </div>
```

Result:
[visual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU4Ve.png)

Result in editor with whitespaces visible:

```
            123456789
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove unnecessary whitespace from Jinja rendered template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775207/remove-unnecessary-whitespace-from-jinja-rendered-template)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε That doesn't help here, since OP isn't using any Jinja blocks.

Comment: @AKX is it? `{{ output }}` is a Jinja expression bock, so it applies.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Sorry, yeah, you're actually correct, the answer just doesn't show you can also use `-` with expressions too.

Answer (score 3):

You're putting those twelve spaces there in your markup. (The `<pre>` tag is special in that it doesn't consume the inner whitespace in the tag.)

Simply: Instead of

```
            <pre>
            {{ output }}
            </pre>
```

do

```
            <pre>{{ output }}</pre>
```

or if you do want to keep the three-lined layout, you can add `-`s to have Jinja eat the whitespace:

```
            <pre>
            {{- output -}}
            </pre>
```

Comment: Yes its working. Thx.